# Does the first version of Linux developed by Linus Torvalds have a GUI?

Tags: linux, gui

Does the first version of Linux developed by Linus Torvalds have a GUI (not necessarily Iconic but something simpler like Midnight Commander)?

Comment: Note that what you call "iconic" is pretty much the definition of a *graphical* user interface; mc is a *text* user interface, or TUI.

Comment: You say "does" (present tense).  Are you asking if any later-developed GUIs like X11 or SVGAlib could run on a Linux 0.0.1 kernel, and mess around with a VGA card from user-space?

Comment: [An interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20060916213448/http://www.cat.org.au/maffew/cat/xfree-dawes.html) with [David Dawes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Dawes) provides some historical details from 1991 on. 1991, the year Linux was conceived, incidentally (or not) was also the first year i386 code (for other *nixes) was incorporated into X11.

Comment: Linux today does not have a GUI so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I thought he developed an OS, not only a kernel.

Comment: @JohnDoea The downvote button literally says _"does not show any research effort"_ so you might take that into consideration before asking.

Comment: That's an opinion which I see no point in commenting on besides that; I remind that anyone has the right to use this button or the other and comments shouldn't be triggering or chatty.

Comment: @JohnDoea No, Linus Torvalds wrote a kernel. The userland was originally Minix, but soon replaced with GNU. The kernel doesn't even have a direct user interface; it relies on the tools such as init, bash and other processes to provide a *user interface*. Yet a kernel is **essential** in a operating system.

Comment: To extend the reference of @vidarlo : Are you familiar with the distinction between [Linux and GNU/Linux](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.en.html)?

Comment: what you saw on mc is a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface), not GUI

Comment: Concurring with @phuclv: Even a clever use of a text terminal is not commonly called a graphical user interface. It is, rather, the opposite (the two opposing ends are text vs. graphics). There is some overlap when a terminal is able to respond to mouse clicks but the mouse support is rather a "backport" from true graphical interfaces for which the mouse was invented. Power users of Norton commander and its clone midnight commander typically use keystrokes because it takes too long to grab and reposition the mouse.

Comment: @pipe Your statement is entirely false, Linux has hundreds of different GUIs.

Comment: @peterh Well, if you mean [menuconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuconfig) or similar, I'm with you, though wikipedia says there's only five.

Comment: @pipe Furthermore, manipulating the terminologies is an obviously evil behavior. Playing the lawyer saying this "Linux is only a kernel" thing might be acceptable in different circumstances. In this circumstance, it is covert hostility: you rob the time of others, and make an interesting discussion into mental waste processing. I won't read your bikeschedding about this. If I *ever* see a post from you, doing the same, you can safely count with my downvote. I stopped the talk with you.

Comment: @peterh Maybe you're on the wrong website then, seeing how the question is closed. "I stopped talking to you" looks a bit silly on a public forum btw, and threatening with irrational downvotes is probably only _helpful_ if moderators have to investigate [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/334517) in the future.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Note, Linux is only a kernel, like `msdos.sys` in DOS or `krnl386.exe` in Windows.

No. It had no GUI, it was purely command line.

In Linus' initial [statement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.os.minix/dlNtH7RRrGA/SwRavCzVE7gJ), roughly with the release of the Linux kernel 0.0.1, we said, he ported bash and gcc to it. He ported probably also the most important GNU tools (make and fileutils (today part of coreutils)).

> I'm doing a (free) operating system (just a hobby, won't be big and
>   professional like gnu) for 386(486) AT clones.  This has been brewing
>   since april, and is starting to get ready.  I'd like any feedback on
>   things people like/dislike in minix, as my OS resembles it somewhat
>   (same physical layout of the file-system (due to practical reasons)
>   among other things).
>
> I've currently ported bash(1.08) and gcc(1.40), and things seem to
>   work. This implies that I'll get something practical within a few
>   months, and I'd like to know what features most people would want. 
>   Any suggestions are welcome, but I won't promise I'll implement them
>   :-)

<sup>Note: This initial mail looks a little bit self-advertising and flamish with the eyes of the today, but it is better to not see that post from the current culture.</sup>

Although X11 was ported to it in a few years, roughly in 1993<sup>1</sup>. It was a huge work, much bigger than writing the kernel itself, but having the kernel made the X11 port possible.

The today obsolete SVGAlib appeared roughly also in that year<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I did not find a reference on the net for that, except my remembers.</sub>

Comment: Self-advertising and flamish? But Linus even says that it's just a hobby that won't be big and professional (boy was he mistaken, but that's another subject). If anything, he seems more humble than usual.

Comment: @forest: Yeah, I don't see what's at all self-advertising and flamish about the *quoted part*, at least. It's a lot more friendly than at least 95% of his emails in the past 20 years, and I'd consider it reasonable form for announcing a related project of interest on a mailing list I moderate.

Comment: The kernel doesn't offer a command line interface (nor a GUI), unless you count that of the boot loader passing parameters when chaining to the kernel (and I pretty much doubt that interface was in place in the early releases either). The kernel does hardware and kernel-internal initialization, then passes control to an init program (whether sysvinit, systemd, Upstart, or something else) that is supposed to get the system to a "useful" state. Try passing `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel on a modern system some time, and you'll probably get a moderate likeness to the early Linux systems.

Comment: Actually the thing that Torvalds developed was indeed just the Linux kernel.  It had no GUI or UI at all.  It took additional things, such as porting a shell like /bin/sh or /bin/csh to give it any UI at all.

Comment: @jwh20: "I've currently ported bash..."

Comment: It depends on the definition of GUI. A VT100 style command line is technically a visual display, some might say a text gui. It's not a line printer or a series of flashing lights, and its not hooked to a braille terminal. It has things like 2 dimensional character addressing, bold, blinking, etc.  And by 'first version' i assume he means the first official release with a version number, not the first time he booted into protected mode and printed 'a' 'b' in task switcher.

Comment: @forest Could be that it was meant as or some people read it as a side-jab at gnu? Like "yeah I'm doing this alone since april and it's ready to hit the fan in contrast to that gnu stuff that's professional and in the making for years". I wouldn't read it like that but perhaps some do. In particular since there has apparently always been a bit of a naming dispute been brewing in some circles. (GNU/Linux vs Linux for the OS). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy

Comment: the name Linux is very well used for the kernel as well as the whole system and OP likely meant the earliest Linux based operational OS / distribution. Though clarifying OP's misconception that if he meant the whole OS, it's not what Linus single-handedly wrote is a valid answer in that case I guess.

Comment: "It depends on the definition of GUI".  No-one ever called a VT100 character interface, not even one that presented menus rather than command lines, a "GUI".

Comment: @FrankHopkins No, back then Linux _was_ just a small side-project. Linus never expected it to take off.

Comment: @donbright - The "G" in GUI standard for *graphical*. A VT100 command line is at best a **T**UI.

Comment: [X386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X386) was available on Linux by August 1992 ([1.2E 1.0.2 supported Linux](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.unix.bsd/vQZnxPoIYEA/G0B0hyz0iYgJ); I don’t know whether any earlier version did).

Comment: @StephenKitt Ok, but Linux was only a hobby-project of student(s) at the time, an "a port to i386 unixes" did not mean a Linux port as well. I suspect, some 386bsd or Minix/Xenix port was more likely first.

Comment: @peterh the first release of X386 in 1991 was for commercial Unix. The release I mention above specifically included patches to allow it to run on Linux. I agree that BSD support probably was available before Linux support ;-). I’m only trying to help by providing references for the last part of your answer...

Comment: @aCVn By "the boot loader passing parameters when chaining to the kernel", do you mean GRUB? If so, you are correct that it wasn't around at that time (indeed, it's not even part of the kernel), and was first released in 1995. I have a vague recollection that it's possible to compile Linux to boot without a bootloader, but the source escapes me, so I may be mistaken.

Comment: @James_pic As I can remember, at the time, Linux image could be written from sector to sector to a floppy disk and it was bootable. There was also a `LOADLIN` tool what could start a Linux kernel from a DOS command prompt. Also `lilo` was used roughly like `grub` today. However, my these remembers are coming from the 1.2 era. Possibly the kernel 0.0.1 was a Minix binary, startable from Minix.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Well, it certainly wouldn't fall flat. GNU has been working on its kernel for something like forty years and it still isn't ready. It doesn't help that it's often been treated as "don't worry, it'll totally be coming soon", and that it was stopped and restarted a couple of times. There are some advantages to the micro-kernel model compared to a monolithic kernel, but... forty years! :D

Comment: @James_pic As pointed out by peterh, GRUB is one way to load the Linux kernel. LILO is another. LOADLIN is a third. Writing it directly to the boot sector and using only the boot process of the BIOS to load it is a fourth. Loading via EFI is a fifth. There's probably a few more I can't think of off the top of my head, and that's only what's available on IBM PC compatibles.

Comment: @aCVn There is kexec, what boots another Linux from a Linux, but it was developed only at around 2.2 or 2.4 . Somewhere I remember rumors to boot a Linux kernel from Windows, too. There is also syslinux/isolinux, it was used mainly on bootcd-s, but worked also from hard disks. It had a network-boot capable fork, too. Embedded architectures, particularly arm on android, tend to use their own bootloader supplied by the manufacturer.

Comment: for blind people, all of these vt100 style terminals are graphical. graph as in the ancient greek root, picture of. if it requires your visual cortex to input information to your brain, it is based on pictures, i.e. its graphical.  especially considering the early linux had mouse interface so a handful of terminal programs could accept mouse/pointer input. its like debating if things like midnight commander are graphical - it uses ANSI graphics, they are literally called ANSI graphics. etc etc. dig through old IBM display manuals, they are called graphic characters or some such.

Comment: @donbright While you have imho right by analyzing the original meaning of the words, the widely accepted meaning of the terminology deviated from it a little bit in the recent decades. Today GUI means that the graphic on the display can be (and is) determined on the pixel level, contrary the character display where it has a fixed set of predefined characters.

Comment: the original question literally asks "a gui"... then says "like midnight commander", which was a textmode program using ansi character graphics, so the point is that back in those days the terminology and thinking was a bit different, as was the thinking, since PC with MS/DOS pixel graphics above 640x480x16 required special expensive video cards that werent even really standardized. I am guessing someone probably built a weird obscure GUI using SVGAlib as well if someone dug hard enough. The "first version of linux" like discussed above is even vague as you cant use a kernel by itself.

Comment: @donbright The question was edited meanwhile, and I did not update the answer yet. But I think ncurses support did not exist in that old version. Afaik at the time even bash did not use ncurses, but I am not sure.

Comment: @peterh I am having a hard time seeing what need bash would have for ncurses even today.

Comment: @aCVn Today libreadline needs it for the command line editing. But it probably did not exist at the time yet.